# angular isn't respecting all my required fields

Tags: angularjs

In my page below everything is working except for the `user.productNumber` input at the bottom. What I mean is that all the "required" fields are keeping the "Create Account" button disabled but it's like the productNumber input is being ignored. How can I get this working?

```
<ion-view title="Sign Up">

  <ion-content>
    <form name="signUpForm">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input data-ng-model="user.email" data-ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" type="email" placeholder="user@mail.net" required>
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input data-ng-model="user.password" type="password" placeholder="password" required>
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input data-ng-model="user.passwordAgain" type="password" placeholder="password (again)" required>
        </label>

        <li class="item item-checkbox">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input data-ng-model="user.newsletter" type="checkbox" checked>
          </label>
          Weekly Newsletter
        </li>

        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input data-ng-modal="user.productNumber" data-ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8}$/" type="text" placeholder="Product Number" required>
        </label>
        <button data-ng-click="createAccountClick()" data-ng-disabled="signUpForm.$invalid" class="button button-full button-positive">
          Create Account
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you mispelled `data-ng-model` with `data-ng-modal`.

Simply change:

```
data-ng-modal="user.productNumber"
```

with

```
data-ng-model="user.productNumber"
```

Comment: Wow.. It's too late to close this question so hopefully someone else benefits from it too. Thanks ryeballar.